# Why does cherrypy say that port isn't free even it is unused port?

Tags: api, cherrypy, salt-stack

Even though I configure a unused port the engine starts and then gives an error saying that it is not free. sometimes-the port is occupied by process python, sometimes it is still open when I check the status after debugging. please let me know what am I doing wrong

This is my salt-api file. rest_cherrypy:

```
port: 28160
host: 10.0.13.122
webhook_disable_auth: True
webhook_url: /hook
ssl_crt: /etc/ssl/private/cert.pem
ssl_key: /etc/ssl/private/key.pem
```

salt-api l debug gives the error:

> ChannelFailures: IOError("Port 28160 not free on '10.0.13.122'",)

Here's the debugging o/p

> Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master
>
> [INFO    ] [24/Nov/2016:12:15:11] ENGINE Started
>      monitorthread'_TimeoutMonitor'.
>      [ERROR   ] [24/Nov/2016:12:15:16] ENGINE Error in 'start' listener 
>      method Server.start of >
>      Traceback (most recent call last):
>      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/process/wspbus.py", line 197, 
>      in publish
>       output.append(listener(*args, **kwargs))
>       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cpserver.py", line 151, in 
>       start
>       ServerAdapter.start(self)
>       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/process/servers.py", line 
>       167, in start
>       wait_for_free_port(*self.bind_addr)
>       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/process/servers.py", line 
>       410, in wait_for_free_port
>       raise IOError("Port %r not free on %r" % (port, host))
>       IOError: Port 28160 not free on '10.0.13.122'
>
> [ERROR   ] [24/Nov/2016:12:15:16] ENGINE Shutting down due to error in start
>       listener:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/process/wspbus.py", line 
>       235, in start
>       self.publish('start')
>       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/process/wspbus.py", line 
>       215, in publish
>       raise exc
>
> ChannelFailures: IOError("Port 28160 not free on '10.0.13.122'",)

Comment: I have encountered similar problems on debian systems - are you on debian or ubuntu?

Comment: .................... .It is ubuntu.

Comment: the problem seems to be that on debian `salt-master` and `salt-api` sometimes collide - there is already an api process running, but one of the init scripts is not aware of it. I guess this is an issue with the debian related scripts bundled with salt. to circumvent this I usually kill the processes the hard way and restart everything. this should be filed as an issue [on github](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues) IMO. but I did not had the time bundle all information necessary for the saltstack team until now. maybe you have? :)

Comment: I was asked to different task as I took too long to sort that out. I am not doing that now.Thanks for responding anyway.